# Expandable floating action button (using Stack) not working in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, floating-action-button

This is my dart file where I want to create a Expandable floating button which is wrapped in Stack widget and I have created a custom IconButton named as CircularButton for Expandable FAB when I try to provide onTap/onPressed gesture in GestureDetector widget or my CircularButton custom widget it does nothing no error and on press of icon it doesnt open to respective app. I tried chaning the return type of customLaunch but that didnt worked too.

Any help is appreciated.
thank you,

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';    
           
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  void customLaunch(command) async {
    if (await canLaunch(command)) {
      await launch(command);
    } else {
      print(' could not launch $command');
    }
  }

  AnimationController animationController;
  Animation degOneTranslationAnimation,
      degTwoTranslationAnimation,
      degThreeTranslationAnimation;
  Animation rotationAnimation;

  double getRadiansFromDegree(double degree) {
    double unitRadian = 57.295779513;
    return degree / unitRadian;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 600));
    degOneTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence(<TweenSequenceItem>[
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.2), weight: 75.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.2, end: 1.0), weight: 25.0),
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degTwoTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence(<TweenSequenceItem>[
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.4), weight: 55.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.4, end: 1.0), weight: 45.0)
    ]).animate(animationController);
    degThreeTranslationAnimation = TweenSequence(<TweenSequenceItem>[
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.75), weight: 35.0),
      TweenSequenceItem<double>(
          tween: Tween<double>(begin: 1.75, end: 1.0), weight: 65.0)
    ]).animate(animationController);
    rotationAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 180.0, end: 0.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(parent: animationController, curve: Curves.easeOut));
    super.initState();
    animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 5,
      child: Scaffold(
                floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
                floatingActionButton: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Transform.translate(
                      offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),
                          degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                      child: Transform(
                        transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                            getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                          ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.black, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                          width: 50,
                          height: 50,
                          child: IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.repeat, color: Colors.white),
                              enableFeedback: true,
                              onPressed: () => customLaunch('https:google.com')),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Transform.translate(
                      offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(225),
                          degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                      child: Transform(
                        transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                            getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                          ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.black, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () => customLaunch('sms:546456464'),
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.chat, color: Colors.white),
                                enableFeedback: true,
                                onPressed: () => {},
                              ),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Transform.translate(
                      offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(180),
                          degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                      child: Transform(
                        transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                            getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                          ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: CircularButton(
                          onPressed: () => customLaunch('tel:+91 9478946545'),
                          color: Colors.black,
                          width: 50,
                          height: 50,
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.call,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Transform(
                      transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                          getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value)),
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: CircularButton(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: 60,
                        height: 60,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.menu,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (animationController.isCompleted) {
                            animationController.reverse();
                          } else {
                            animationController.forward();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
}
```

```html
class CircularButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Color color;
  final Icon icon;
  final dynamic onPressed;

  CircularButton({this.color, this.width, this.height, this.icon, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color, shape: BoxShape.circle),
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: IconButton(icon: icon, enableFeedback: true, onPressed: onPressed),
    );
  }
}
```

I just want to **open other apps onTap of expanded floating buttons** but it isnt opening though no error in code still not working.
It doesnt only takes onpressed paramater  or onTap.

Comment: Are you sure your animation-only button isn't obscuring the remaining widgets for gesture detection?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz So If its animation-only then how can I make It detect gesture with animation also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just needed to add this the IgnorePointer in stack so that it detects gesture and ignore animations for that particular area
the code which I changed is as,

```
 floatingActionButton: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
            right: 30,
            bottom: 30,
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              children: <Widget>[
                IgnorePointer(    // this edit made it worked     
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    height: 150.0,
                    width: 150.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: Offset.fromDirection(getRadiansFromDegree(270),
                      degOneTranslationAnimation.value * 100),
                  child: Transform(
                    transform: Matrix4.rotationZ(
                        getRadiansFromDegree(rotationAnimation.value))
                      ..scale(degOneTranslationAnimation.value),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CircularButton(
                      onClick: () => customLaunch('www.cigarettewala.com'),
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.repeat,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score -1):

`Stack` If used with animation, button click functionality will be broken.

I had the same problem as you! Put the `Stack` in a `container` and give it a certain width.

`Stack` It must have a certain size so that the `widgets` do not protrude from it.